# Program will not compile using modules, adding and subtracting

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to allow you to enter two integers, and to type an, A, S, or M to add, subtract, or multiply, relatively. Unfortunately, it does not do this, and I was wondering why.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char choice;
    int num1, num2;
    int getNums();
    int operatorChoice()
    int multiply(int, int);
    int subtract(int, int);
    int add(int, int);
    void outputResult(int);
    getNums();
    int result;
    operatorChoice();
    if(choice == 'A'){
        add(num1,num2);
    }
    if(choice == 'S'){
        subtract(num1, num2);
    }else{
        multiply(num1,num2);
        outputResult(result);
        return 0;
    }
}
int getNums(){
    int num1,num2;
    cout << "Enter an integer " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter an integer " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    return num1, num2;
}
int operatorChoice(){
    char choice;
    cout << "Enter A to add, S to subtract, or M to multiply " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    while(choice != 'A' && choice !='S' && choice != 'M'){
        cout << "Invalid choice. Enter A to add, S to subtract, or M to 
multiply ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    return choice;
}
int add(){
    int num1, num2;
    int result;
    result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
}
int subtract(){
    int num1, num2;
    int result;
    result = num1 - num2;
    return result;
}
int multiply(){
    int num1, num2;
    int result;
    result = num1 * num2;
    return result;
}
void outputResult(){
    int result;
    cout << "The result is " << result << endl;
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
  ./ccAwzJxh.o: In function 'main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference to 'multiply(int, 
int)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1a): undefined reference to 
'outputResult(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

It also gave me errors for most of the other functions, until I intialized variables in them.

Comment: Give us an [MCVE]

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [Ask].  Please format your code properly.

Comment: And those aren't modules, they are functions.

Comment: There are several problems with this code, and you wrote all of this without testing any of it. Start with something simpler. Start with `HelloWorld`. When you have that working perfectly, then build up, adding complexity a little at at time, testing at every step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: Hey @jwdonahue how do you expand to How to ask?

Comment: @GrantGarrison `[ask]`. List of secret codes here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @user4581301 cool **edit:** really really cool!

Comment: your case does compile, it does not link, because there is no such function as `outputResult(int)` you only have `outputResult()` with no args which is no-go in c++.

Comment: Time to open that C++ book you bought for studying...

Comment: Please rollback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definitions for your functions are after `int main()`, so the program doesn't know what you are referring to. Move the functions before `main`, or declare the functions before `main` so it knows what you are referring to. For example:

```
int main(){
    function(0);
}
int function(int a){
    return a;
}
```

The above code won't work when called because the compiler has no idea what `function` is, so it gives an error.

```
int function(int a);
int main(){
    function(0);
}
int function(int a){
    return a;
}
```

This code will **declare** a function. This will cause the function to already be known to the compiler when `function` is called, and the compiler will compile the code. This is the most commonly used (I believe) way to do this, as it causes no problems with using functions in functions.

```
int function(int a){
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    function(0);
}
```

This just defines `function` before it is called. This is known as a **definition**.

**Note:** Declarations do not require the exact variables.
This:

```
int function(int x);
int main(){
    function(0);
}
int function(int a){
    return a;
}
```

will compile and work correctly. Also, this:

```
int function();
int function(int x);
int main(){
    function(0);
}
int function(int a){
    return a;
}
```

works fine too. What a great language we program in! [C++ redeclaration inconsistency/interestingness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205371/c-redeclaration-inconsistency-interestingness) has some useful information about this.

Comment: I moved them before main, but that still said that there were errors with values not being declared.

Comment: @PrestonFreeman You forgot your variable names. You just wrote int.