# C++ redeclaration inconsistency/interestingness

Tags: c++, function, standards, header-files, redeclaration

I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204971/c-messed-up-optional-argument-forced-to-be-mandatory/49204988?noredirect=1#comment85415242_49204988) when I thought of this example:

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int i);
void func();

int main (){
    func();
    return 0;
}
void func(){}
```

In the above example, the code compiles fine. However, in the below example, the code does not compile correctly:

```
#include <iostream>

void func();
int func();

int main (){
    func();
    return 0;
}
void func(){}
```

This is the error that occurs when this code is compiled (in clang++):

```
file.cpp:4:5: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be
  overloaded
int func();
```

I would expect an error like this both times.

I fiddled around with the code a bit, and for some completely odd reason, it seems that the linker completely ignores incorrect declarations. Now this allows for some **very** weird code. For example this header file would be legal:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE
#define EXAMPLE
void func();
void func(int a);
void func(int b);
void func(int a, int b);
void func(int a, short b);
void func(int w);
void func(short b);
#endif
```

Why? Why in the world does any of this work? Is this just a C++ standard failure? Compiler failure? "Feature"? Actual Feature? (That is all one question by the way.)

P.S. While I'm waiting for an answer, I'm going to be over here taking advantage of this for pre-adding features in code that will probably end up in production.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. It's fine to overload on arguments, but you can't overload on the return type. If you could overload on the return type, there would have to be information flowing backwards. With the example header file you gave, you have several duplicated declarations for a `void func(int)`, but that's not a problem. What is your question?

Comment: Is the question: Why does the compiler allow duplicated function declarations? In that case, one potential "use" is to have different default arguments in different declarations, but that would be very questionable. I am not sure why the compiler would allow duplication declarations.

Comment: @Justin The question is why would the compiler/linker allow for many declarations without even a warning. All of the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is function overload, argument names are not taken into account (argument types or its count are different).

The second is function redeclaration (argument types and count are the same) with changed return type that is forbidden. Overloading of return type only is not allowed. The compiler told it to you.

Comment: Oh. Um. Well. So this made obfuscation about 100% easier. Gah. I'm going to write my own compiler that doesn't support this. **EVEN** `-wall` allows that. Cringe. (I'm talking about the parameter names.)

Comment: @GrantGarrison You can even declare a function without parameter names, using only types. Try it!

Comment: @GrantGarrison, someone once said, with great power comes great responsibility :)